# Get the indices of for a numpy array of N integers

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy

I have a numpy arrays of length N with unique integers ranging from 0 to N-1, such as

```
2 3 1 0
```

I would like to get a mapping from the elements to their indice

```
0 -> 3
1 -> 2
2 -> 0
3 -> 1
```

How can I do this very fast?  In my problem setting, the numpy array can be very large ( N is almost 10^7).

The result can be stored in another mumpy array of the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no pattern in the values, you'll to iterate over the array for an O(n) solution:

```py
arr = np.array([2, 3, 1, 0])
indices = np.zeros(arr.size, dtype=int)
for i in range(size):
    indices[arr[i]] = i
```

Comment: Thanks. Could I assume that "indices[arr]=np.arange(arr.size)" would be faster?